# Decomposing a graph into paths

Tags: graphs

> Given a simple graph with $n$ vertices, show that you can remove all edges in $O(n\log n)$ rounds, where in each round you are allowed to remove all edges of any (single) path.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 3):

A classical result of Lovász ([On covering of graphs](http://web.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/scans/lovasz-on_covering_of_graphs.pdf)) states that a graph on $n$ vertices can be decomposed into at most $n/2$ paths and cycles, and so into at most $n$ paths.

Comment: thanks but its somehow too complicated i think proving nlogn would be much easier i would appreciate if you could give me answer for nlogn 
thanks in advance:)

Comment: I don't work for you.

Comment: i mean no offences

Comment: It's hard for me to guess which argument the setter is looking for without further context.

Comment: i think you're right the further context the better. thanks!

Comment: Only you know the context. It's further input you have to provide.